# STL - what is the problem of the following code?

Tags: c++, stl

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <string>
#include <map>
using namespace std;

class NiftyEmailProgram {
private:
    typedef map<string, string> NicknameMap;
    NicknameMap nicknames;

public:
    void ShowEmailAddress(const string& nickname) const
    {
        NicknameMap::const_iterator i = nicknames.find(nickname);

        if ( i != nicknames.end() )
        {
        }
    }

};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    printf("Hello World!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

When I compile the above code in VC6.0, I have seen tons of warnings. If I use Warning Level 4 and treat all warnings as error, then the output error from STLFilt is as follows:

```
Compiling...
t3.cpp
c:\devstudio_6.0\vc98\include\xtree(118): error C2220: warning treated as error - no object file generated
    c:\devstudio_6.0\vc98\include\map(46): see reference to class template instantiation 'map<string,string>' being compiled
    C:\TEMP\t3\t3.cpp(12): see reference to class template instantiation 'map<string,string>' being compiled
Error executing cl.exe.  


t3.exe - 1 error(s), 26 warning(s)
Tool returned code: 0
```

Now, what is the problem of this code and how do I fix it?

Thank you

Comment: I remember this occurring and simply ignored the warning. It would be good to know how to avoid the warning.

Comment: Remove `stdafx.h` from the includes?

Comment: Why are you using a 12 year old compiler?

Comment: The code reads just fine. VC 6.0 is most probably to blame.

Comment: VC 6 is to blame. VC 8 deprecates some perfectly valid STL functions (eg. `std::copy`). This annoys me everyday. You have to disable the warnings on a per case basis.

Comment: @FredOverflow, because the company who pays my bill adopted, is adopting and will adopt VC6.0 as the main workhorse.

Comment: You should ask them if they are planning to upgrade to Windows 98 while they're at it. Seeing as how it's contemporary with VC6.

Comment: @Karl, you forget, for the workplace, it was Windows NT. What did NT stand for again!?!

Comment: @Nim: * **raising my hand up** * pick me, pick me! Nice try??!

Comment: Hey everybody, don't pick on him for retaining an old compiler - sometimes you have libraries you depend on that can't be upgraded, or a large body of code that wouldn't be cost-effective to upgrade. P.S. I've made an addition to my answer, check it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to post the non-treated warnings.

However, I too remember that I got some level 4 warning from `<xtree>` in `<map>` , that could be safely ignored (IIRC it was [C4702](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-warnings/compiler-warning-level-4-c4702?view=msvc-160), which is harmless).

To avoid the warning, I put around the STL `#include`s some appropriate `#pragma warning` directives (enclosed in the correct `#ifdef`s to have them considered only on MSVC++, thanks to *@Alexandre C.* for reminding me of it):

```
#ifdef _MSC_VER
    //Disable the C4702 warning for the following headers
    #pragma warning(push)
    #pragma warning(disable:4702)
#endif // _MSC_VER
//map STL container
#include <map>
//list STL container
#include <list>
//vector STL container
#include <vector>
#ifdef _MSC_VER
    #pragma warning(pop)
#endif
```

You could also simply lower the warning level to 3 (or even lower) just in that section with:

```
#ifdef _MSC_VER
    // Lower the warning level to 3 just for this section
    #pragma warning(push, 3)
#endif
//map STL container
#include <map>
//list STL container
#include <list>
//vector STL container
#include <vector>
#ifdef _MSC_VER
    #pragma warning(pop)
#endif // _MSC_VER
```

For more info, see the [documentation of `#pragma warning`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/warning?view=msvc-160).

Comment: For portability, you can segregate the `#pragma` s with `#ifdef _MSC_VER` ... `#endif`.

Comment: @Alexandre C.: Uh, you're perfectly right, I'll fix it right now.

Comment: Sorry for nitpicking, but while you're at it, take the habit of enabling it for a specific version since this is know to behave well on MSVC7.

Comment: @André Caron: I got that level 4 warning also on MSVC7.1, so I'd leave it as it is, also because, in general, you'd expect that the standard library headers are tested enough that the warnings you may get from them aren't important.

Answer (score 2):

If I remember correctly, the mangled function names created by STL easily exceed some built-in limit, and this is what triggers the warning. It's unfortunate that you used STLFilt to keep us from seeing the actual warnings produced by the compiler.

The only work-around I found was to use typedefs and/or derived classes to shorten the names used in the template.

As the others have mentioned, the best and easiest fix would be to upgrade your compiler.

**Edit:** I tried this on my own VC6 and the error was exactly as I remembered:

```
c:\program files\microsoft visual studio\vc98\include\xtree(118) : warning C4786: 'std::_Tree<std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> >,std::pair<std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> > const ,
std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> > >,std::map<std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> >,std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> >,std::less<std::basic_string<cha
r,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> > >,std::allocator<std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> > > >::_Kfn,std::less<std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> > >,std::allocator<std::basi
c_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> > > >' : identifier was truncated to '255' characters in the debug information
        c:\program files\microsoft visual studio\vc98\include\map(46) : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::_Tree<std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> >,std::pair<std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<
char>,std::allocator<char> > const ,std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> > >,std::map<std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> >,std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<cha
r> >,std::less<std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> > >,std::allocator<std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> > > >::_Kfn,std::less<std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocato
r<char> > >,std::allocator<std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> > > >' being compiled
```

The workaround I mentioned earlier isn't enough, because with the shortest class name possible the name of an iterator still exceeds 255 characters. The solution is to put this before the `#include <map>`:

```
#pragma warning(disable:4786)
```

Comment: the total warning message is of size 60285, I am not allowed to post that big chunk of text here. thank you

Comment: @q0987: you may post it on pastebin or something like that.

Comment: @q0987, I presume most of the warnings are duplicates, couldn't you post just one or two?